# How To Make a Marquee UILabel in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uilabel, marquee

How do I implement a marquee for the iOS UILabel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very much sure but i think you have to do animation by frame.when you set the co-ordinates for the label put variables like x,y instead of the values of parameters 1 and 2. and put this in a animation timer with changing value of x and y.

similar code, it is for image you can do it for label also:-

```
// Build array of images, cycling through image names
  for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frame_%d.jpg", i]]];

  // Animated images - centered on screen
  animatedImages = [[UIImageView alloc] 
     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
        (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - (IMAGE_WIDTH / 2), 
        (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - (IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2) + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
        IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
  animatedImages.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];

  // One cycle through all the images takes 1.5 seconds
  animatedImages.animationDuration = 1.0;

  // Repeat forever
  animatedImages.animationRepeatCount = -1;

  // Add subview and make window visible
  [window addSubview:animatedImages];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // Start it up
  animatedImages.startAnimating;

  // Wait 5 seconds, then stop animation
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1000];
```

i Hope it helps you.. :)